# How to split a string on the second match

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string:

```
foo="re-9619-add-selling-office";
```

I'd like to break up the string on the second `-` (dash) into variable1 and variable2.  I want to end up with `variable1=re-9619` and `variable2=add-selling-office`

I tried it using grep and awk, but now I not sure that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done using [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), you don't need an external utility.

```
$ foo="re-9619-add-selling-office"
$ variable2=${foo#*-*-}
$ variable1=${foo%-"$variable2"}
$
$ echo $variable1
re-9619
$ echo $variable2
add-selling-office
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following once. Where `first` variable will have value like `re-9619` and `second` shell variable will have value like `add-selling-office`

```
first=$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/\([^-]*-[^-]*\)-.*/\1/')
second=$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/\([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)-\(.*\)/\3/')
```

***Explanation:***

- `echo "$foo" | sed 's/\([^-]*-[^-]*\)-.*/\1/'`: Printing value of foo variable and passing its output to `sed` command. In `sed` I am using substitute capability to perform substitution, `\([^-]*-[^-]*\)-.*`(which has everything from starting of value to till 2nd occurrence of `-` in back reference in it). Then substituting whole value with 1st captured back reference value which will become only `re-9619`.
- `echo "$foo" | sed 's/\([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)-\(.*\)/\3/'`: Logic is same as above mentioned command. Using `sed`'s capability of substitution with using back reference capability of it. Here we are printing everything after 2nd occurrence of `-`.

***NOTE:*** `second=$(echo "$foo" | sed -E "s/$first-(.*)/\1/")` could also help as per @User123's comments.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: we can also directly substitute the "first" variable into second `sed` command just to make it to look a bit simpler and readable :)... `second=$(echo "$foo" | sed -E "s/"$first"-\(.*\)/\1/')`

Comment: @User123, yeah cool, thanks for letting know, I have added solution with credits cheers and happy learning :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single `sed + read` way:

```sh
foo="re-9619-add-selling-office"
read var1 var2 < <(sed -E 's/^([^-]*-[^-]*)-/\1 /' <<< "$foo")

# check variables
declare -p var1 var2
declare -- var1="re-9619"
declare -- var2="add-selling-office"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)):

```sh
variable1=$(echo $foo | cut -d '-' -f 1-2)
variable2=$(echo $foo | cut -d '-' -f 3-)
```

This is the result:

```sh
>> echo $variable1
re-9619
>> echo $variable2
add-selling-office
```